# Removing single quotes from SQS message id in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, unicode, ascii, amazon-sqs

I am getting a message ID from AWS SQS like this format:

```
u'messageId': u'9c8a1bff-9ef2-411e-a163-ce631856ded3'
```

I grab the messageid value and decode with following:

```
    messageid =message['messageId']
    messageid =jobgroupid.encode('ascii','ignore')
    messageid =messageid .replace("''", "")
```

When I print it in python, it shows no quotes just the string value.

```
9c8a1bff-9ef2-411e-a163-ce631856ded3
```

This is then uploaded to s3 as a dat file. I grab the dat file locally and then read the file and it showing following:

```
'9c8a1bff-9ef2-411e-a163-ce631856ded3'
```

Why is there single quotes still around this text?

Comment: Would you agree that this question isn't reproducible just with the code you provided? Please make it minimal. e.g. remove single quotes from a string? (what is the output), it wouldn't need to depend on AWS/SQS. Or do you call SQS (how?) without single quotes and is it adding them? etc. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Suggest you simplify this by removing SQS and the encoding steps temporarily. Simply take a string, write it to S3, then retrieve it. Get that to work first.

Comment: FYI, there are no quotes in your data if that is printing the content of a dictionary.  Printing a dictionary or list in Python 2 displays strings with quotes, escape codes for non-printable and non-ASCII characters, and a leading `u` to differentiate Unicode from byte strings.  This is so you can tell the exact content of the container.  A [mcve] would help.

Comment: What is `jobgroupid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mistaking string contents with string representation, and making a mess out of it.

Strings, as data in Python, be then unicode strings or byte-strings in Python 2 are *viewed* with surrounding `'` quotes whenever you look at their representation.

The methods and functions meant to present the string content to the final user (which includes recording then on a file), do show that content without the surrounding quotes.

In Python 2, to see the string content in the console you use the `print` statement.

The code that is putting the quotes on your output ".dat" file is not presented here - that code is what puts the string there. If you were recording a raw file yourself, just calling `myfile.write(messageid)` would write it without the quotes. I tend to think you are using some 3rd party code to write your dat file, passing in your data as a dictionary - that code is including the quotes on the output.

The only way you'd get these quotes if you were calling file.write directly is either if you write the `repr` of your data, like in: `myfile.write(repr(messageid))`, or if this messageid is inside a list or Python dictionay, and you write the string representation of that data structure to your file - like in `file.write(str(my_dict_with_data))`

And moreover, it might have reasons for that. `.dat` is a generic extension for data, and have no real specifications - in many cases, the qutes around data like that, (for example in JSON files), is a desirable thing.